# Mustache.js to Angular.js, triple bracers in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mustache

I have the following in Mustache.js:

```
<div>{{{icon.tmpl}}}</div>
```

`icon.tmpl` is a template on its own with the following content:

```
<div id="{{id}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></div>
```

In Mustache.js, thanks to the triple bracers, this works perfectly, both levels of templates gets compiled. Now I can't make this work in Angular.js. The second embedded template does not get compiled, but is instead surrounded by quotation marks "..."

How to make this work in Angular?

Comment: You would probably want to make your own directive in this case.

Comment: Isn't this what `ngInclude` provides?

Comment: ngInclude would probably work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use an ngInclude or create a directive. Here is an example of an icon directive that essentially just replaces any `icon` element with the div info you've specified.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NK5bOFvsgpMGeTkteMif?p=preview

html:

```
<icon></icon>
```

js:

```
app.directive('icon', function ( $compile, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div id="{{id}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></div>'
        }

    })
```

The directive could just as easily be something like `<div class="icon">` or `<div icon>` and you could apply the template to it.

An example of the `ngInclude`:

```
<ng-include src="'icon.html'"></ng-include>
```

Where `icon.html` just has your template info.  Make sure that `id` is in the scope in both cases.

Comment: I used <ng-include src="templates.alarm"></ng-include> and my alarms shows perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: If you use a directive you could generalize it and do something like: <icon type="send"></icon> and <icon type="mail"></icon> and the directive would just adjust the class on the template.  Something to consider for the future.  Here is an example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/iCq3nP0qSmpuRc6I0ves?p=preview